# Zsh color inside command substitution

Tags: bash, zsh

Coloring output of commands in zsh is kind of simple. Consider the following example in zsh prompt:

`print -P "%F{cyan}$(date +'%H:%M:%S')$reset"`

You get cyan HH:MM:SS as expected. It works in prompt as expected as well. Now suppose I want to color minutes and seconds in a different color. I didn't manage to achieve it using `%F{color}`, is it possible?

I can make it work using ANSI codes, but even then it works with print and does not work when used as prompt in ~/.zshrc:

`print -P "%F{cyan}$(date +'%H:\e[38;5;82m%M:%S')"` - works in zsh

`RPS1="%F{cyan}$(date +'%H:\e[38;5;82m%M:%S')"` as a right prompt gives `17:\e[38;5;82m14:11`

What am I missing? How do I escape the color code or even better use zsh `%F{color}` construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have some quoting problems.

It could not been used double quoets; the `$(date...)` part would be expanded, `RPS1` would not be updated for each prompts.
It could be *unescaped* any escape(`\e`)s. (especially `\e[38;5;82m` part for `date` command)

So, for `PS`-like strings, it would be useful to quote using `$'...'` forms like this:

```
setopt promptsubst
RPS1=$'%F{cyan}$(date +"%H:%%{\e[38;5;82m%%}%M:%S")%{\e[0m%}'
```

If you can find the color index for `\e[38;5;82m`:

```
RPS1=$'%F{cyan}$(date +"%H:%%{%%F{82}%%}%M:%S")%{\e[0m%}'
```

It could be found by some tools like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

---

Note: `\e[38;5;82m` and `\e[0m` are surrounded with `%{...%}`.

> `%{...%}`
>   Include a string as a literal escape sequence. The string within the braces should not change the cursor position. Brace pairs can nest.
>
> --- [zshmisc(1), Visual Effects, Prompt Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects)

Note2: `setopt promptsubst`. without this option, `print -P ...` nor `RPS1=...` does not work.

> `PROMPT_SUBST`
>
> If set, parameter expansion, command substitution and arithmetic expansion are performed in prompts. Substitutions within prompts do not affect the command status.
>
> --- [zshoptions(1), PROMPT_SUBST, zsh options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPTSUBST)

```
setopt promptsubst
print -P $'%F{cyan}$(date +"%H:%%{\e[38;5;82m%%}%M:%S")%{\e[0m%}'
;# => 23:54:18
```

---

PS: `%F{color}` constructs would be easier for copy-pasting variables with dumping them on screen.

```
> print $RPS1 ;# this output could not been used for copy-pasting
%F{cyan}$(date +"%H:%%{%%}%M:%S")%{%}
> print $RPS1 | cat -v ;# this either (but close to)
%F{cyan}$(date +"%H:%%{^[[38;5;82m%%}%M:%S")%{^[[0m%}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but none of your examples work neither in `print -P` nor in `~/.zshrc`. Did you test them yourself?

Comment: Yes, I did. It works here. I missed to suggest issuing `setopt promptsubst` .

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I didn't have it as well. Now it works. Thanks. It is not using %F, but it allows 256 colors, so I am marking as solved unless Rene Knop comes up with %F version.

Comment: Thanks taking your time!

Comment: I've added %F version. %F can take a 256-color index. I had misunderstood the question somehow.

Comment: That's a very nice example. Btw it's the first working example I found, that shows the usage of escape sequences in the `date` formatting argument.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1 - Calling `date` only *once*:

```
d=$(date +'%H:%M:%S');h=${d:0:2};ms=${d:3:5};
RPS1="%F{cyan}$h:%F{green}$ms%F{default}"
```

Version 2 - Calling `date` *twice*:

```
RPS1="%F{cyan}$(date +'%H'):%F{green}$(date +'%M:%S')%F{default}"
```

Comment: Your solution works, but really what it does is it calls `date` two times.

Comment: Well, it would nice to know why %F does not work as well, so really I cannot mark it as solved.

Comment: It's correct don't to mark it as solved at the moment.:-) I think it's a good but not the exact answer to your question. I'm on my way to find a solution using `%F` ;-) This is an interesting case.

Comment: Finally I found a way using %F. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the external command `date`: Zsh has built-in [prompt escapes for displaying date and time](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Date-and-time):

> […]
>
> `%D{string}`
>
> *string* is formatted using the `strftime` function. See man page strftime(3) for more details.
>
> […]

So the simple coloring can be achieved with

```
RPS1='%F{cyan}%D{%H:%M:%S}%f'
```

In order to have two colors, you can just use two `%D{…}` blocks and color them differently

```
RPS1="%F{cyan}%D{%H}:%F{82}%D{%M:%S}"
```

This can be as complex as you need (want):

```
RPS1='%F{154}%D{%H}%F{155}:%F{156}%D{%M}%F{157}:%F{158}%D{%S}'
```